# How to detect fractal / pattern in image with OpenCv or Tensorflow?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, opencv3.0

Consider this image

[image: Batik Nitik]

How to detect the fractal / template that builds up the whole image with OpenCV / Tensorflow?
I'm trying to extract the fractal from that image and output it as a new image.
Thanks in advance